# How to split the dataset in python based on the number of records

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to divide a dataframe into two based on a number

```
train = corpus.iloc[:, :10000]
test = corpus.iloc[:, 10000:]
```

This is the code that i am using.

I am getting the below error as :

```
 AttributeError: iloc not found
```

Is iloc not part of python3? Is there any other method to split the data based on the number of records to be split?

**Edit**
As mentioned by the user @craig, i loc is pandas and the datatype that i have is of sparse matrix (scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix)

Comment: `.iloc` is a method of Dataframes from the `pandas` module. Are you using `pandas`? If so, you will be more likely to get an answer if you show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Craig - oh ok, then its a mistake from my side. The corpus is of type - scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Comment: @Craig - is it possible to split a matrix in python?

Comment: I believe that you can use regular array slicing notation like `corpus[:, :10000]`.

Comment: @Craig - Thanks a lot for your help and pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `iloc`, can use a row slice directly:

**Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(10))
df_first_half = df[:5]
df_second_half = df[5:]
```

**Scipy**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
x = csr_matrix((10, 3), dtype=np.int8)
x_first_half = x[:5].toarray()
x_second_half = x[5:].toarray()
```

If you're unfamiliar with the `[5:]` notation, see: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html. Briefly, it's a one-dimensional slice (rows). Multi-dimensional slicing, e.g. [5:, :1], is also available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just noticed that it is not a pandas dataframe. but it is a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix. Is it possible to split the data in this datatype?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just noticed that it is not a pandas dataframe. but it is a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix. Is it possible to split the data in this datatype?

Comment: @rmharrision - Thank you very much. It has worked. Thanks for providing the link as well